# No Sound / Intel Corporation Device 5a98

Tags: 16.04, drivers, sound, alsa, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but my sound isn't working.

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a98 (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 7270
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 124
    Memory at c2b18000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at c2900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl
```

pvucontrol or alsamixer only shows HDMI sound output but not more.
I have a special kernel:

```
Linux Elm 4.14.29-galliumos #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 25 03:40:24 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

because I have a chromebook, but only the kernel, the rest of the system is Ubuntu 16.04